# What does this "degree" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> the Triumph of the French government over the English does in fact
> afford me a degree of pleasure which it is very difficult to
> disguise.' ...

Does this mean "a certain amount of"?
However it sounds odd here.

I thought it meant "a lot of pleasure" here.
What do you think?

---

[Source](http://www.delanceyplace.com/index.php)

Comment: Please add the link to the original source to the body of your question. I think there might be a typo in the text, or that might actually be correct from the source... But I have no way to know that in absence of the source.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does mean "a certain amount of", and **a degree of** (something) is often used in this way. The specific phrase **a degree of pleasure** is particularly common.

The speaker's subtext does in fact suggest that he has a great deal of pleasure, but the phrasing (using **a degree of**) is understatement.